# How to use a foreign key which has a different column name to the primary key?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I am getting a parse error. The error is produced by the Image table. I am trying to use a foreign key which has a different column name than the primary key.

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS fastpic;


CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS fastpic;


USE fastpic;


CREATE TABLE user
  (
  email_address varchar(255),
  name varchar (255),
  user_id INT NOT NULL,

   PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
   created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   );

CREATE TABLE image
   (
   filename varchar (255),
   image_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (image_id),
   uploaded_by_user_id INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (uploaded_by_user_id),
   REFERENCES user(user_id),
   ON DELETE CASCADE),
   created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
   );

CREATE TABLE commentcomment
   (
    image_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (image_id),
    REFERENCES image(image_id),
    ON DELETE CASCADE),
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY (user_id),
    REFERENCES user(user_id),
    comment_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (comment_id),
    TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    imageurl varchar (1000) NOT NULL,
    comment varchar(2500),
    created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    );

CREATE TABLE follow
     (
      user_id INT NOT NULL,
      FOREIGN KEY (user_id),
      REFERENCES user(user_id),
      ON DELETE CASCADE),
      following_id INT NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (following_id),
      timestamp_id INT NOT NULL,
      created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
      )
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of synthax errors in your script. Some of them include:

- Commas before every references and cascade on.
- A closing bracket after cascade on delete.
- A semi-column in the `follow` table creation code, just before the last closing bracket.
- No column name to `TIMESTAMP` after primary key definition in `commentcomment` table.

You can see [MySQL tutorials](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/) for more info on using MySQL as a DDL(Data Definition Language). 
Here is an [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18168c).

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS fastpic;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS fastpic;
USE fastpic;

CREATE TABLE user ( 
 email_address varchar(255),
 name varchar (255),
 user_id INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (user_id),
 created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE image ( 
 filename varchar (255),
 image_id INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (image_id),
 uploaded_by_user_id INT NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (uploaded_by_user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id),
 created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
);

CREATE TABLE commentcomment ( 
 image_id INT NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (image_id) REFERENCES image(image_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 user_id INT NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id),
 comment_id INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (comment_id),
 -- [No_Column name]TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 imageurl varchar (1000) NOT NULL,
 comment varchar(2500),
 created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE follow ( 
 user_id INT NOT NULL,
 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES user(user_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 following_id INT NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (following_id),
 timestamp_id INT NOT NULL,
 created_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 modified_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help - it works - I think also I had not created keys before using FKs and PKs.